# Logstash 5.x stdout logging

Tags: logstash

Running v5.2.2 installed on Ubuntu via .deb file, haven't changed any of the `logstash.yml` or log4j configurations and I'm using the standard

```
output {
  stdout {
    codec => "rubydebug"
  }
}
```

In my configuration,

But cannot find the actual lines that are being written, `/var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log` is not empty but does not show the relevant lines.

I thought it had something to do with the codec, but changing to `plain` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Found it at `/var/log/upstart/logstash.log`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15645599)

Comment: @Psi What? Yes it does.

Comment: @Psi It answers the question precisely, I should know as I wrote both the question AND the answer.

Comment: zombie reply, but it might have been worth just adding a little more gumpf around what settings set that etc. \shrug. Just keeps the fussy chaps happy ;) @OrWeinberger